How can I install python and pip via conda without internet access during environment creation in AzureML?
I need to create an environment in AzureML, however there is no public internet access configured in the network settings of my workspace. I can access my Python packages locally on a storage account and install them. However, the conda file also requires python and pip to be installed. I know my base image already has them installed but I cannot get conda to recognize this.
Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu20.04
# Set work dir
WORKDIR /
# Define environment variables for Conda
ENV CONDA_PREFIX=/azureml-envs/myenv
ENV CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=$CONDA_PREFIX
ENV PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/bin:$PATH
# This is needed for mpi to locate libpython
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# Copy the environment.yml file to the image
COPY conda.yml .

# Set up Conda configuration
RUN conda config --add channels https://<SA>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/<directory_to_wheel_packages> && \
    conda config --set channel_priority strict && \
    conda config --remove channels defaults && \
    conda config --set offline true
    
# Create the Conda environment
RUN conda env create -p $CONDA_PREFIX -f conda.yml && \
    rm environment.yml && \
    conda run -p $CONDA_PREFIX pip cache purge && \
    conda clean -a -y

I want to set up conda so that it doesn't check the default channels, only my storage account + the MCR base image that has python and pip installed on it.
conda file:
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
  - pip
  - pip:
    - https://<SA>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/<directory_to_wheel_packages>/*.whl<SAS>
    - https://<SA>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/<directory_to_wheel_packages>/*.whl<SAS>
# more packages

Error message on AML:
2024-06-27T15:06:47: Step 8/9 : RUN conda config --add channels https://<SA>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/<directory_to_wheel_packages> &&     conda config --set channel_priority strict &&     conda config --remove channels defaults &&     conda config --set offline true
2024-06-27T15:06:47:  ---> Running in ******
2024-06-27T15:06:51: Removing intermediate container *******
2024-06-27T15:06:51:  ---> ************
2024-06-27T15:06:51: Step 9/9 : RUN conda env create -p $CONDA_PREFIX -f conda.yml &&     rm environment.yml &&     conda run -p $CONDA_PREFIX pip cache purge &&     conda clean -a -y
2024-06-27T15:06:51:  ---> Running in ***************
2024-06-27T15:06:52: Channels:
2024-06-27T15:06:52:  - 
2024-06-27T15:06:52: Platform: linux-64
2024-06-27T15:06:52: Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
2024-06-27T15:06:52: Solving environment: ...working... failed
2024-06-27T15:06:52: [91m
2024-06-27T15:06:52: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
2024-06-27T15:06:52:   - python=3.9*
2024-06-27T15:06:52:   - pip


2024-06-27T15:06:52: The command '/bin/sh -c conda env create -p $CONDA_PREFIX -f conda.yml &&     rm conda.yml &&     conda run -p $CONDA_PREFIX pip cache purge &&     conda clean -a -y' returned a non-zero code: 1

2024-06-27T15:06:52: [0m

2024-06-27T15:06:52: CalledProcessError(1, ['docker', 'build', '-f', 'Dockerfile', '.', '-t', '***.azurecr.io/azureml/*****', '-t', '*****.azurecr.io/azureml/*********:1'])

2024-06-27T15:06:52: Building docker image failed with exit code: 1

The requirement is that these packages must not be installed locally in the workspace, because of network restrictions. Also, I must be able to do this by creating an environment and specifying a dockerfile. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Basically, you want to install the packages in storage account only right?

conda checks for repodata.json in the default location, you can overwrite it with your preferred location in the conda confing in your own base image. You can install your python dependencies in the base environment (not recommended by conda nor AzureML) if you are fine with the defaults for python interpreter and resolver version in the base image base conda environment. For that just RUN pip install requirement.txt after COPY requirements.txt ..
As a side note, having hardcoded SAS in the docker context doesn't seem secure, and probably more concerning than allowlisted access to anaconda.org.

Thanks for your reply. Two questions:

How do you mean I can overwrite the repodata.json?
One thing is that I have a hard requirement about all wheel packages (of subdep and dependencies) to be installed together. I am afraid if I simply install onto the base image, other pre-installed packages there will interfere. Would still be able to use conda. If not possible, maybe a pipenv might work on the base image? What do you think?

